# Checkstyle custom check does not work on gradle checkstyle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

## Question

I have created own custom check for checkstyle and **it works on commandline and via maven checkstyle plugin**.
However **via gradle checkstyle plugin, it occurs below error**.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my-project:checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create Root Module: config {C:\Users\[path to my project]\build\tmp\resource\string8421659201972573805.txt}, classpath { ...many of classpathes. not "null" }.
```

Whenever exclude custom check from checkstyle.xml, the task works.

How to make custom check works on gradle?

## Versions

- checkstyle: 8.37
- maven checkstyle plugin version: 3.1.2
- gradle version: 5.6.2

## Implementation

- custom check

```
public class MyCheck extends AbstractCheck {
...
```

- checkstyle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name = "Checker">
    ...
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        ...
        <module name="package.to.my.check.MyCheck"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

Custom check class and checkstyle.xml are packaged into an artifact named "mycheck-module".

- pom.xml (It works)

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.2</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
              <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
              <version>8.37</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>package.to.my.check.module</groupId>
              <artifactId>mycheck-module</artifactId>
              <version>[version]</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <sourceDirectories>
              <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
            </sourceDirectories>
            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
            <enableFilesSummary>true</enableFilesSummary>
            <maxAllowedViolations>0</maxAllowedViolations>
            <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
            <failOnViolation>
              false
            </failOnViolation>

            <propertyExpansion>
              checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir=${project.basedir}
            </propertyExpansion>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

- build.gradle (It does not work)

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'package.to.my.check.module:mycheck-module:[version]'
    }
}

...

// Set up checkstyle
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

def checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir = file("${rootDir}/suppressCheckstyle")

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.37'
    sourceSets = [it.sourceSets.main]

    config = resources.text.fromString(getClass().getResourceAsStream('checkstyle.xml').text)
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
    maxErrors = 0

    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir = checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir
}
```

Comment: From stacktrace, instantiation or custom check is failed via gradle plugin.  Message: "Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: Unable to instantiate 'package.to.my.check.MyCheck' class, it is also not possible to instantiate it as null. Please recheck that class name is specified as canonical name or read how to configure short name usage https://checkstyle.org/config.htm
l#Packages. Please also recheck that provided ClassLoader to Checker is configured correctly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved myself.
You can add your dependency into checkstyle with [Append] in below:

- build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'package.to.my.check.module:mycheck-module:[version]'
    }
}

...

// Set up checkstyle
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

def checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir = file("${rootDir}/suppressCheckstyle")

// ================ [Append] ================
dependencies {
    checkstyle 'package.to.my.check.module:mycheck-module:[version]'
}
// ================ [Append] ================

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = '8.37'
    sourceSets = [it.sourceSets.main]

    config = resources.text.fromString(getClass().getResourceAsStream('checkstyle.xml').text)
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
    maxErrors = 0

    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir = checkstyleSuppressionConfigDir
}
```